# How to find employee transfers in and the transfers out from an employee audit?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, count

I have a table (EmployeeAudit) that looks as such:

| EmployeeID | OldDept | NewDept |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Software | Design |
| 234 | Design | Engineering |
| 345 | Design | Software |
| 345 | Advertising | Software |

I want to create a table that looks like this:

| Dept | TransfersIn | TransfersOut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Software | 2 | 1 |
| Design | 1 | 2 |
| Advertising | 0 | 0 |
| Engineering | 1 | 1 |

I know that I probably need something like:

```
SELECT
    Dept,
    ... AS TransfersIn,
    COUNTIF(NewDept != OldDept) AS TransfersOut
FROM EmployeeAudit
GROUP BY
    TransfersIn,
    TransfersOut
```

Comment: mysql and google bigquery are two different rdbms products. Removed conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use. Also, it would be great if you had an additional table listing all departments, otherwise your query will be rather complex.

Comment: see answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/72034577/5221944