# How to find employee department changes?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that has the old departments and new departments of various employees:

| EmployeeID | OldDept | NewDept |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Design | Design |
| 234 | Software | Engineering |
| 345 | Design | Software |
| 456 | Advertising | Software |

How can I create a table that looks like this:

| Dept | TransfersIn | TransfersOut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Software | 2 | 1 |
| Design | 0 | 1 |
| Advertising | 0 | 1 |
| Engineering | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
select * from (
  select NewDept as Department, count(*) Transfers, 'TransfersIn' Mode from your_table
  where NewDept != OldDept
  group by Department, Mode
  union all
  select OldDept as Department, count(*) Transfers, 'TransfersOut' Mode from your_table
  where NewDept != OldDept
  group by Department, Mode
)
pivot (sum(Transfers) for mode in ('TransfersIn', 'TransfersOut'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: What if oldDept == newDept?

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use this query to find the transfers Out:

```
SELECT 
    OldDept AS Dept,
    COUNTIF(OldDept != NewDept) As TransfersOut
FROM table
GROUPBY
    EmployeeID,
    OldDept,
    NewDept
```

Comment: I think that this would just show the count of transfers that this particular department is involved in... Not TransfersOut

Answer (score 0):

You can use A FUL OUTER JOIN which thw subselects

```
SELECT 
   COALESCE(OldDept,NewDept) AS Dept, IFNULL(TransfersIn,0) AS TransfersIn   , IFNULL(TransfersOut) AS TransfersOut
FROM
(SELECT NewDept, COUNT(*) AS TransfersIn FROM tabl1 GROUP BY NewDept) As Ne
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT OldDept, COUNT(*) AS TransfersOut FROM tabl1 GROUP BY NewDept) Ol
ON Ne.NewDept = Ol.OldDept
```

Comment: What if oldDept == newDept?

Comment: I don't understand your question, full outer join joins bith subqueries, and if old is equal to new add it to the same row, every row that has 1 department missing, would be added with 0, Coalesce will take Vaöue that is nit NULL., so that all departmenst independent of existing in old or new wil be dosüalyed,